# Using two cache providers in Play Framework at the same time?

Tags: scala, caching, redis, memcached, playframework-2.3

In my Play (2.3, scala) application i would like to use two different caches for different use cases. E.g. `redis` cache for one UC, `memcached` for another. Is there a way to configure this?

Ideally make one cache provider default, and specify another when using.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be done.

Try using a service like Apache Zookeeper:
Configure your caching settings (like server and port numbers) for each application there, also keep a boolean variable around for each one.

If the boolean is set to *false* for one cache, this signals to use the other caching mechanism, and the other way round if the booleans are differently set.

Comment: This does not answer the user's question clearly. Maybe consider adding an example to illustrate "configure your settings" and "If boolean is false for one cache use the other" parts of your answer.